# What is use of background colour in question lists?

Tags: support, design

For filtered question lists, if seems that new questions have background colour applied until I have actually seen them in the list.  On successive viewing, it is no longer present.

However for Arduino lists of all questions, I can find no rhyme or reason to the use of such.  When there is background colour, I can see the question in the list or even open it, but there is no change following this.  What am I missing here? Surely it is intended to impart some piece of information.  I had read many FAQs and questions, but can find no reference to such behaviour.

Comment: Favourite/ignored tags are the only thing that alter the background in question lists AFAIK... do you have any favourite/ignored tags?

Comment: @Cai ok, I think I understand now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I now see that this is the result of having favourite tags.